# When updating collection document in mongo, update it in every other document or collection where it is used

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am quite new to noSQL databases and have an issue which I am not sure how to resolve.
I have two collections Services and Products.

The schema for Service is the following:

```
    name: { type: String, required: 'Enter name' },
    price: { type: Number, required: 'Enter price' },
    description: { type: String},
    duration: { type: String, required: 'Enter duration' },
    products: {type: [Product]}
```

The schema for Product is the following:

```
    name: { type: String, required: 'Enter name' },
    description: { type: String},
    qty: { type: Number, required: 'Enter quantity' },
    unitsOfMeasure: { type: String, default: UOM.Piece},
    qtyPerService: {type: Number}
```

Now as you can see Service contains a collection of Products. When I update certain Product in my Products collection, it is not updated in the Services containing this exact product. I know it is not because Service products are not linked to their source documents in the Products collection, but I do not know how to achieve this.

Any tips or ideas are appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ref` and `Populate` of mongoose because it is very comfortable and meets your needs, please check this [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)